# Is picture location info retained when I share a photo?

Tags: ios, photos, sharing, geolocation, privacy

When I send a picture to a friend (e.g. via Messages, Mail, or Tweet), is the location information in that photo preserved? In other words, can they see where I took that photo?

What about when I use 3rd party apps such as Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

This is a feature usually only offered by professional photo software. Removing metadata (like `EXIF` or `GPS`) requires an additional step by the one that wants to share his/her photograph.

Aperture for example offers to export picture as either an **original** or a **version**. When you choose to export a **version** the  meta- and gps-data is removed from the original.

I know from experience that sharing via the following options does not remove these and from pictures:

- Mail for OS X
- Tweetdeck for OS X
- Uploading via a web browser

Here's what the metadata of an *export as original* look like:

[image][image]

Here's what the metadata of an *export as version* by Aperture look like. This is an exported version of the same original. The data will differ depending on the export options for a version.

[image][image]

Comment: Given that the question asks "is location data is *retained*" and your answer clearly and correctly states that it usually is by Facebook or Twitter uploads, shouldn't your first statement be **YES** instead of No?

Comment: @patrix Ups.... Mistake corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the iPhone strips location data before sharing via Email or text message - whether you like it or not.

Now, this is true for the standard photo app in the iphone - this may not be true for 3rd party photo apps.

The official Facebook app for iphone also strips location info.

Comment: can anyone confirm if this is still true now in 2019?