# How can I remove geolocation info from a picture on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, geolocation, privacy

Since geolocation info is [usually preserved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55827/is-picture-location-info-retained-when-i-share-a-photo) when I share a photo from my iPhone, I was wondering what the simplest way is to remove this geolocation info from an existing picture.

To be clear: I don't want to take a new photo, and I don't want to disable the option that geotags my photos. I just want to take an existing photo, remove the location info (e.g. by duplicating it, while retaining the original size), and then send it to a friend.

Comment: Screenshot it when previewing it and send the screenshot? You'll lose a TON of quality that way, but shy of transferring it to your computer and using a utility to strip the information, I don't know of any other way on-device to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There's an App called [GeoZapper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/geozapper/id432763213?mt=8) ($1-$2) (or a free, limited [Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/geozapper-lite/id438843105?mt=8) version), which will remove geolocation info from pictures.

If you know of any other apps or alternative methods to remove this info, please post them.

Answer (score 1):

There are various PC software packages that will strip the information. One that works on PC is described here:

From - http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=435525301297:

> The best way to remove geo tags from your images is by using tool
>   called Geotag Security. As the name suggest, this tool secures your
>   images from Geo Tags. This tool is very simple to use and with one
>   simple click you can delete geo tags from all your images. You will
>   see following window when you run this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) as described [here](http://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2011/11/removing-geotag-data-from-jpgs.html/):

```
exiftool -gps:all= image.jpg
```